# vscode c++ launch.json program path

Tags: visual-studio-code

I cannot find how to set program path in `launch.json`.

here is my workspace tree.

```
workspace
|__folderA
    |__src
    |__obj ( here is the program path )
```

How can I set obj file path?

Comment: use [variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually this is enough:

```json
{
  "name": "C++ Launch",
  "type": "cppdbg",
  "request": "launch",

  // assign your target program path here, using absolute path or relative path to workspace
  "program": "${workspaceFolder}/folderA/obj/your_program_name",

  "args": [],
  "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
  "environment": []
}
```

Refer to https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference for details.